# Would Stack Overflow be a reasonable place to ask which version of Python I should use?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, recommendation-questions

I have a question that effectively boils down to, "which version of Python should I use to write a new module for public distribution?". Is this a reasonable question to ask on Stack Overflow?

I believe it may run counter to the policy of not asking for recommendations from the help pages. If it is not the correct place to ask, then please let me know where it would be best to ask this question.

Comment: Sounds likely to be _opinion based_. Asking for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) might be go better there, while making context and restrictions clear.

Comment: Yep, that looks like what I'm wanting. If you make this into a full answer if be happy to mark it as accepted.

Comment: If you asked this question in the SO [Python chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python), a resounding "Python 3" would be the answer. It's bad enough that some people are still writing Python 2 code, with its official End of Life looming, providing a new Python 2-only library is counterproductive to the goal of encouraging such people to get their act together & migrate to Python 3. Almost all libraries & APIs of significance now cater to Python 3, although I realise that there are still a handful of exceptions, eg Maya.

Comment: The real question is which Python 3 minor version thigh. I've not done anything more than small gone utilities in Python so I'm not sure if that possibly a silly question, or if I should just write for the lowest version of python that will run what I want it to.

Comment: @JakeConkerton-Darby: no it's not. *"Any reasonably recent version"* perfectly adequate, i.e. 3.6.x. 3.7.0 unless you're in production and you distrust its stability, in which case 3.6.x, until 3.7.1 comes out.

Comment: Apart from SO's explicit prohibition, questions seeking a recommendation often exhibit another serious flaw: a lack of research effort. You can address both concerns by beefing up your question and reframing it. For example: _I need to choose between X and Y. These are the benefits and drawbacks I see for X,  and these are the benefits and drawbacks I see for Y. Have I missed anything significant?_ In that way you show research effort, and you are not asking for a recommendation. And such a question might invite more insightful responses than a simple _"Should I use X or Y?"_.

Comment: Once you go 3.x, there are very few scenarios where a later minor version is going to be a problem. For example, there are almost no 3.x modules out there that don't work in 3.4, and only a few (mostly those that do bytecode-hacking) that don't work in 3.7. You do lose WIndows NT4/2000 and OS/2 (and VMS, which had releases up to 3.3, but they usually didn't work), but how often do you care? So, even if someone is on 3.1, there's no reason they can't install 3.7, or run your PyInstaller-based 3.7 app. Or you could just deploy with Docker and it doesn't matter at all anymore. :)

Comment: But, on the other hand, if you weren't planning to use, say, f-strings, or argparse interleaved options, or stable dict order, or any other features added after 3.4, then it doesn't really hurt you to use 3.4. (Although if you're not planning to use f-strings, you might want to rethink that one…) PS, this back-and-forth discussion over 2 days is exactly why you shouldn't ask the question you cleverly didn't ask. :)

Answer (score 38):

On the positive side, I'm *really* happy you decided to ask before posting the question.  This shows that you're willing to come to Meta and at least inquire if it's reasonable or not.

Now to the meat of your question.  The answer is...*probably not*.  I say that because the [clock is running out on Python 2 support](https://pythonclock.org/), and it would seem incredibly silly for a Python developer to develop anything *new* that wasn't immediately thrown away in Python 2.

By and large, though, the choice of what version of a language or VM or environment your module runs on is best answered by *you*, anyway.  You know more about your target audience and scope of the module than any stranger on the Internet, and you should leverage that knowledge to be sure that you're building on something that you believe will lead to wide adoption.

Comment: Yeah, I've been taking some of my spare time to help moderate Stack Overflow, so I've seen enough off topic questions to smell one that doesn't seem quite right, and didn't want to fall afoul of asking one myself. As for Python it'll definitely be 3.x, but the question really becomes which x would be best. I'm all for latest version, but I want the module to be widely applicable for people in general.

Comment: @JakeConkerton-Darby Well then the answer is rather trivial: 3.0 and above.

Comment: @Gimby Well, the number of people who require 3.0 and 3.1 could well be 0. Anyone who was enough of an early adopter to jump on 3.x before it was really usable is almost surely on 3.7, or maybe a local build of 3.8-pre, or a least 3.6. (Sadly, 3.2 actually came with a distros that a few people are still using.)